# How to convert function insertion module pass to intrinsic to inline

Tags: llvm, inline-assembly, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

**PROBLEM:**
I currently have a traditional module instrumentation pass that
inserts new function calls into a given IR according to some logic
(inserted functions are external from a small lib that is later linked
to given program). Running experiments, my overhead is from
the cost of executing a function call to the library function.

**What I am trying to do:**
I would like to inline these function bodies into the IR of
the given program to get rid of this bottleneck. I assume an intrinsic
would be a clean way of doing this, since an intrinsic function would
be expanded to its function body when being lowered to ASM (please
correct me if my understanding is incorrect here, this is my first
time working with intrinsics/LTO).

**Current Status:**

My original library call definition:

```
void register_my_mem(void *user_vaddr){
  ... C code ...
}
```

So far:

- I have created a def in: llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/IntrinsicsX86.td

  let TargetPrefix = "x86" in {
  def int_x86_register_mem : GCCBuiltin<"__builtin_register_my_mem">,
  Intrinsic<[], [llvm_anyint_ty], []>;
  }
- Added another def in:
  otwm/llvm-project/clang/include/clang/Basic/BuiltinsX86.def

  TARGET_BUILTIN(__builtin_register_my_mem, "vv*", "", "")
- Added my library source (*.c, *.h) to the compiler-rt/lib/test_lib
  and added to CMakeLists.txt
- Replaced the function insertion with trying to insert the intrinsic
  instead in: llvm/lib/Transforms/Instrumentation/myModulePass.cpp

WAS:

```
FunctionCallee sm_func =
curr_inst->getModule()->getOrInsertFunction("register_my_mem",
func_type);
ArrayRef<Value*> args = {
      builder.CreatePointerCast(sm_arg_val, currType->getPointerTo())
};
builder.CreateCall(sm_func, args);
```

NEW:

```
Intrinsic::ID aREGISTER(Intrinsic::x86_register_my_mem);
Function *sm_func = Intrinsic::getDeclaration(currFunc->getParent(),
aREGISTER, func_type);
ArrayRef<Value*> args = {
      builder.CreatePointerCast(sm_arg_val, currType->getPointerTo())
};
builder.CreateCall(sm_func, args);
```

---

**Questions:**

1. If my logic for inserting the intrinsic functions shouldnt be a
   module pass, where do i put it?
2. Am I confusing LTO with intrinsics?
3. Do I put my library function definitions into the following files as mentioned in
   http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2017-June/114322.html as for example EmitRegisterMyMem()?

   - clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenFunction.cpp - define llvm::Instrinsic::ID
   - clang/lib/CodeGen/CodeGenFunction.h - declare llvm::Intrinsic::ID

My LLVM compiles, so it is semantically correct, but currently when
trying to insert this function call, LLVM segfaults saying "Not a valid type for function argument!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing multiple issues here.

Indeed, you're confusing LTO with intrinsics. Intrinsics are special "functions" that are either expanded into special instructions by a backend or lowered to library function calls. This is certainly not something you're going to achieve. You don't need an intrinsic at all, you'd just need to inline the function call in question: either by hands (from your module pass) or via LTO, indeed.

The particular error comes because you're declaring your intrinsic as receiving an integer argument (and this is how the declaration would look like), but:

- asking the declaration of variadic intrinsic with invalid type (I'd assume your `func_type` is a non-integer type)
- passing pointer argument

Hope this makes an issue clear.

---

See also:  https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for clearing up the issue @Anton Korobeynikov.

After reading your explanation, I also believe that I have to use LTO to accomplish what I am trying to do. I especially found this link very useful: https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html. It seems that I am now on a right path.

Comment: This looks like a comment, a reply to the existing answer.  Please don't post an *answer* if you aren't answering the question.  You can post comments on people's answers to your own question even if you don't have enough rep to comment in other cases.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. After considering it, I still strongly believe that my reply is also a part of the "answer" since I share a helpful link that resolves my question. Others that run into similar issue can benefit from it @PeterCordes

Comment: Ok, then the problem is that it's a link-only answer.  [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231).  Sounds like it would be a good comment or edit-suggestion for Anton's answer to include that link, but the link on its own doesn't make an answer.  (And most of the text in your "answer" is a reply to Anton and commentary about your progress, not anything that will help future readers.)